# Скрывающиеся блоки с помощью jquery (продолжение)

Tags: jquery, javascript

Добрый вечер! Я уже задавал вопрос по поводу "Скрывающиеся блоки с помощью jquery" и получил на него правильный ответ.

> `Добрый вечер! Исходные данные: каталог товаров, каждый товар которого на странице отображается друг под другом. Проблема в следующем: Необходимо чтобы товары выводились в виде списка и какой-нибудь метки "+" (например "Товар для Дома 1, [+] "), при нажатии на которую раскрывался блок с информацией конкретного товара. Также необходимо чтобы была функция "скрыть все блоки" и "раскрыть все блоки".

Буду благодарен, если подскажете в какую сторону копать (jqueryui перекопал, но не разобрался) или кинете линк на уже реализованный пример.`

Ответ был получен следующий:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.showinfo').click(function () { // при клике на .showinfo скрываем/раскрываем блок с инфой
            $(this).parent().find('.productinfo').toggle();
            $(this).text($(this).text() == 'показать' ? 'скрыть' : 'показать');
            return false;
        });
        $('#hide-all').click(function () { // при клике на #hide-all скрываем все блоки, меняем тексты кнопок   
            $('.productinfo').hide('slow');
            $('.showinfo').text('показать');
            return false;
        });
        $('#show-all').click(function () { // при клике на #show-all раскрываем все блоки, меняем тексты кнопок  
            $('.productinfo').show('slow');
            $('.showinfo').text('скрыть');
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>

<a href="#" id="hide-all">Скрыть все</a>  
<a href="#" id="show-all">Раскрыть все</a>

<div id="product-15" class="product">  
<!-- код -->   
<div class="productinfo" style="display: none;">текст с описание продукта</div> 
<a href="#" class="showinfo">показать</a> 
</div>
```

Теперь задача усложняется. Необходимо, чтобы было не две кнопки "Скрыть все" и "Раскрыть все", а одна, которая бы выполняла те же функции и соответственно меняла своё название при клике.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А может попробуете самостоятельно усложнить? Тем более, что решение предоставленное Вам достаточно наглядное. Идея такова: теперь, вместо кликов на каждой из кнопок (скрыть-показать), надо отслеживать клики только по одной. У Вас всё есть (и смена названия кнопки и отображение/скрытие блоков). Присмотритесь.

Comment: ИМХО для одной кнопки это даже проще написать

Comment: блин, вот если все присмотрятся на последние темы.

1."Изучение языка программирования PHP"
2."На чём лучше писать сайты?"
3."Где продолжить обучение школьнику-программисту(Москва)?"
4."Выбор языка программирования на будущее [закрыт]"
5."Стать профессионалом."
и т.д. их много особенно за последнюю неделю. Сказывается мне, что через год тут будут вопросы типа:"Начал писать сайт. На этих мыслях и закончил, подскажите на чем его писать, в какой программе, и сколько можно взять с заказчика.Учитывая что это мой первый сайт". Учился в Спб ИТМО, на фил.факе. но захотел стать программистом.

Comment: На этих мыслях и закончил :DDD